# For any positive integer $n$, let $f_n:[0,1] \to\mathbb R$ be defined by $f_n(x)=\frac x{nx+1}$ for $x \in [0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis

For any positive integer $n$, let $f_n:[0,1] \to\mathbb R$ be defined by $f_n(x)=\frac x{nx+1}$ for $x \in [0,1]$. Then

(a) The sequence $\{f_n(x)\}$ is uniformly converges to $[0,1]$

(b) The sequence $\{f_n'(x)\}$ of derivative of $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly converges

(c) The sequence $\{\int_{0}^1 f_n(x) dx\}$ is convergent

(d) the sequence $\{\int_0^1 f_n'(x) dx\}$ is convergent

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

I correct only the first question and the other are not very different. First we should determinate the point-wise limit. It's simple to see that the sequence $(f_n)$ is point-wise convergent to the zero function $f$. Now to we should compute
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|$$
so notice that
$$f'_n(x)=\frac{1}{(nx+1)^2}>0$$
so the function $f_n$ is increasing and then
$$\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=f_n(1)=\frac1{n+1}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$$
so the convergence is uniform.